# Threadpool not starting any new threads, but is below limit

Tags: vb.net, async-await, threadpool, windbg

I have a app that uses async tasks to get Data from a MQTT server.
After I updated my System to Windows 11 I started noticing the Problem that the async tasks are not starting after the App runs for some Days.
This Worked fine before I upraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11.
Checking with a Debugger, I noticed that the Threadpool is set to minimum 16 tasks, but currently only has 1 task witch is waiting for another tasks that is not starting.
I also checked a Dump with Windbg and got this Result from !ThreadPool

```
CPU utilization: 9%
Worker Thread: Total: 1 Running: 0 Idle: 1 MaxLimit: 32767 MinLimit: 16
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 1
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread:Total: 1 Free: 1 MaxFree: 32 CurrentLimit: 1 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 16
```

My Code is basicly

```
Sub Test()
StartUpMQTT().Wait()
End Sub
Private Async Function StartUpMQTT() As Task
MQTTClient = Await Net.Mqtt.MqttClient.CreateAsync(strWebLink, Configuration) 'This is the Line where it waits for the unstarted task.
sessionState = Await MQTTClient.ConnectAsync(New MqttClientCredentials("TestAuslesung"))
End function
```

For now I changed my StartUpMQTT().Wait() to StartUpMQTT().Wait(5000), but I have to wait if this solves the issue of the whole app hanging.

Anything I can try to prevent this from happening/freezing the app, other than my change?

Comment: *Your code* isn't starting any threads at all.  `await` doesn't start a thread. It's used to await an already active asynchronous operation without blocking the current thread and returns execution to the caller when the async operation completes. On Windows all IO is performed by the OS asynchronously, sometimes with the help of a specialized IO threadpool. Blocking operations are emulated by the OS.

Comment: A disk or network operation doesn't need the CPU, it only has to await until the device or remote server responds. No threads are needed for this. The remote server may fail to respond though, or delay the response. The URL or DNS name may be wrong, which means it may take up to 15 seconds before DNS reports the address is invalid

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html